# matlab mark a certain domain beneath the x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, axis

Is it possible to mark a certain domain beneath the x-axis in matlab plot?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html)s. You might have to experiment some extra, but here goes:

A bar that spans over the entire x-axis will be:

```
x_ends = [0.131 0.908];
```

In your case, the length of the x-axis is `2.5` (from 0 to 2.5). That means that the length of one `dx` is:

```
dx = diff(x_ends) / 2.5;
```

If you want a bar that goes from `0.3` to `0.5`, the length will be:

```
bar_length = dx * (0.5 - 0.3);
```

Since you want the bar to start in 0.3, you will have to add that to your coordinates:

```
x_bar =  [0.3 0.5]*dx+x_ends(1);
bar((1:100)/50,floor(rand(1,100)*10));
annotation('line',x_bar,[.1,.1],'Color','r','LineWidth',3);
```

This produces:

[image]

Of course, if you change the axis or something similar, you will have to change a few things in the above.

To get an extra tick at `0.3`:

```
ax_tick = get(gca,'xtick')
set(gca, 'xtick', sort([ax_tick 0.3]))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You, But this is the best there is? Because I need to be between x=0.3 to x=0.5. How do I set it to be there?